# Will the Detonate Singularity upgrade work if the Singularity is detonated by a biotic power?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The Detonate upgrade description is as follows: "Detonate Singularity when the field dies to inflict 375 damage across 5 meters". Does the field have to die of old age, or will a violent death via biotic detonation still trigger the extra damage?

Upon further testing, a Singularity will disappear after 2 biotic detonations have been performed on affected enemies. It is safe to assume that Singularity will detonate properly if only a single biotic detonation has been performed.

Answer (score 1):

when the singularity dies out, it "explodes". you can hear it because it makes a loud warping sound
likewise, it does affect the explosion of a biotic detonation.

Comment: I can't seem to hear the difference between an upgraded and a regular version of Singularity being detonated. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: other than my ears, no sorry